Python port checker not working on Linux; just returns all ports
#Python code for simple port scanning

import socket #importing library 

listofports = []

ip = socket.gethostbyname (socket.gethostname()) #getting ip-address of host

for port in range(65535):    #check for all available ports
    try:
        serv = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM) # create a new socket
        serv.bind((ip,port)) # bind socket with address
    except:
            listofports.append(port)

serv.close() #close connection

print(*listofports, sep=';')

Script runs fine in Windows and returns the ports but when I run on Fedora Linux it just starts printing port numbers 1; 2; 3; 4; 5; and so on, and keeps going to 65535.
I expect a list of open ports on the computer I'm running the script on.

Have you tried printing the exception on linux yet? I would recommend also breaking out of the for loop to minimize unneeded output.

For the first 1024 ports Linux will need root privileges to bind to them.

the idea is the script will try to bind to the port if it cannot the port is in use and the exception is what I am printing,

@StuartDyer except Exception as e: print(e) ... And reading why it fails to bind the port (permission, port in use, etc)

the error is [Errno 13] Permission denied

i believe that and the comment from @KlausD. answers some of your question (up to port 1024)

now if i set a range from 2000, 65535 i get no output, it just runs and finishes

do you want open ports listed? then you should append before the except (also, close your port once you're done with it not at the end)

ok, i'll have to read up, ive been learning python for about 2 days so far so no idea how to fix yet
